# Give the sets $A=\{-4,-1,0,3,4,7,8,9,10\}$ $B=\{-5,-4,-3,-2,3,4,20\}$ $C=\{-6,3,4,8,10,11,13,20\}$ Then calcule $(A^c\cap B^c)△C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help with this exercise.

Given the sets
$$A=\{-4,-1,0,3,4,7,8,9,10\}$$
$$B=\{-5,-4,-3,-2,3,4,20\}$$
$$C=\{-6,3,4,8,10,11,13,20\}$$

Then calculate
$$(A^c\cap B^c)△C$$

---

I know that $(A^c\cap B^c)=(A\cup B)^c$ and
$$A\cup B=\{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,3,4,7,8,9,10,20\}$$
But How I calcule $(A\cup B)^c$??

Comment: Does your universe consist only of the sets $A, B$ and $C$? If so, look at the elements in $C$ that are not in $A \cup B$. If not, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: In such a problem, the universal set must be specified. It wasn't here, so we have no way of knowing what $A^c$ and $B^c$ are supposed to be.

Comment: What operation is $\triangle$?